# How to disable iOS push notification grouping programmatically?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

There's setting to disable push notification grouping in ios. But i want to programmatically disable the notification. Is there any way?

Comment: Notifications group by some sort of ID. Don't remember what it's named or where you set it, but if you post local notifications you can group them by that ID. If they're remote notifications, you'd have to create an extension or something that receives the notifications and decides how they're presented, and *then* group them by given ID. If you just want to disable the grouping, you'd have to do this and just give them separate random ID's. Don't know of any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I've seen is to have different groups for notifications, although, I'm not sure it's the best:

```
let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
notificationContent.title = "Hello!"
notificationContent.body = "Test notification"
notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
notificationContent.threadIdentifier = "random_thread_identifier"
notificationContent.summaryArgument = ""
```